# 'Session expired error' on UI while uploading file through Protractor automation. I'm using 'sendKeys' to upload the file

Tags: angular, selenium-webdriver, file-upload, protractor

I am trying to upload files (xlsx) through the `sendKeys` option on to the Angular UI but the tests fail on the UI with:

```
Your request was rejected due to a session timeout. Refresh the page to begin a new session
```

On debugging more, I found out -behind the scenes it throws out '403: Forbidden' error which doesn't make sense because I can perform the same operation manually successfully. Here's my code:

```
async clickChooseButtonCrct(moduleName: string) {
var click_element = element(by.id(moduleName));
browser.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", click_element);
if (moduleName = 'nameOfModule') {
return await 
click_element.element(by.css('input[type=file]')).sendKeys("absolute path 
of the file");
}
```

Comment: add your test script and the complete error to more input on the issue

Comment: Never mind! The issue was with XSRF-TOKEN into the HTTP request in the angular code. It was fixed by the development team and then the test worked fine.